# A Fearsome Shout

Tags: magic

"And there I was, ambushed by cliff climbing bandits!  I was outnumbered ten to one," the other patrons at the mead-hall groaned.  They had heard this story too many times to count, "but I remembered my greatest ally [FUS RO DAH!](https://youtu.be/T44Am7JoYuY?t=82)"

For any of the readers who have played Skyrim, this is one of the easiest (and most fun) past times in the game (second only to killing Lydia).  When you "shout" (or Thu'um) you use the power of the dragon language (dovahzul) to create really awesome effects (like throwing people or objects around).

TL;DR In Skyrim, you can shout dragon words to blow stuff up.

**Actual Question:** I have a superhero (the hero part doesn't really apply so like a super) that can use his voice to bend the world into submission (blow stuff up or something).  What is the most likely setting (post-apocalyptic, <strike>fantasy</strike>, modern, etc, where it could retain a certain mystery about it, but have concrete rules (insert believably here). (YES I am one of those "hard magic" freaks, and if you couldn't tell, I would prefer a not fantasy setting.)

**Edit:** Bonus points for explanation.

Comment: So you want a "hard magic" black canary? Im sure there is alot out there on the basis of her power.

Comment: Close, but instead of just sonic disruption, he can play with any aspect of his surroundings, including calming people, making fire, etc.

Comment: Well, making fire is just causing molecules to move at a high speed, so it is very similar to sonic disruption. Having what could be acquainted to a sirens' voice would be harder ro explain. Though there are studies to see how we react to different frequencies.

Comment: are you by any chance referring to [Black Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bolt)?

Comment: @user6760 Yes and no, that might work very well as an explanation, but the power is WAY more varied (like skyrim shout varied)

Answer (score 3):

Current time, person has realy powerfull vocal cords and can cry in resonant frequencies to break glass.

[image: http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view1/4184077/breaking-glass-w-voice-o.gif]

Probably he can cry with [with low frequency pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound) to inflict fear.
Like they stated in wikipedia -

> One study has suggested that infrasound may cause feelings of awe or fear 
>   in humans. It also was suggested that since it is not consciously 
>   perceived, it may make people feel vaguely that odd or supernatural events > are taking place

[Infrasound linked to spooky effects](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/3077192/)